# Spring Boot & kubernetes JVM can not go over 1 CPU

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, jvm, google-kubernetes-engine

After deploying my spring boot application (2.7.3), with the following configuration:

- CPU req: 1.2
- CPU limit: no limit
- image: "gcr.io/distroless/java17:nonroot"
- JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-XX:MinRAMPercentage=60.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0"
- GKE 1.21.11-gke.1900  with cos_containerd

it seems that under heavy load my system can not go over 1 CPU usage as seen in the following picture:

[image]

Anyone have faced similar situation ?

Comment: What's your java CPU/processer config set at? You've only shared your memory (ram) config but are asking about CPU...

Comment: yes @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i did not set any specific config for CPU in the JVM except the deployment limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your application process may be single threaded? If not, try to add JVM options `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and check in the standard output for CPU related values like `ActiveProcessorCount`.

Comment: int ActiveProcessorCount                     = -1 which align with the no CPU limit

Comment: starting to think that it might be caused by gke node

Answer (score 0):

Find out that the micrometer metrics are actually used as % of usage, which mean it actually work as expected.